# How to zip specifically file folders older than 60 days via powershell?

Tags: powershell

```
$backup= Compress-Archive -Path 'desired path' -CompressionLevel Fastest -DestinationPath 'desired path'
$backup
```

I am able to zip up the files in the folder but figuring how to only select files that are 60 days or older in specific is my issue. How would I go about something like this?

Ive looked at pieces of code like this:

```
$LastWrite = (get-date).AddDays(-30)

$Files = Get-ChildItem -Filter "server.log*" -Recurse -File | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -le $LastWrite}

ForEach ($File in $Files) {
    $File | Compress-Archive -DestinationPath "$($File.fullname).zip"
}
```

but I am kind of lost

Comment: What's wrong with your code?

Comment: Instead of (-30) it should be (-60)

Comment: The first part works, but I need help on how to add selection of only file folder older than 60 days to zip up

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right: you would like to add all affected files to one zip.

This should work for you:

```
$LastWrite = (get-date).AddDays(-60)

$Files2Compress = Get-ChildItem -Filter "server.log*" -Recurse -File | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -le $LastWrite}

$zipName = (Get-Date).ToString() + '.zip'

Compress-Archive -Path $Files2Compress.FullName -DestinationPath $zipName
```

Comment: I am looking to create a script where when ran in a folder it will zip up all folders that are older than 60 days. The filter would be not server logs but file folders that contain data inside. TLDR Just a script when double clicked will start to zip files that are older than 60 days I tried what you sent but didn't seem to work